# How to use count condition on template in Terraform

Tags: azure, templates, terraform

In the belo code, I trying to fetch azure secret ( if exists) from keyvault and render it to generate template.

```
...
< Keyvault definition >

data "azurerm_key_vault_secret" "win_admin_pass" {
count = ${var.cnt} # either 0 and 1
name         = "vm-winpw"
key_vault_id = data.azurerm_key_vault.keyvault.id
}

data "template_files" "wininv"{
count = ${var.cnt} # either 0 and 1
template = file(ansible/inventory.tpl)
var = {
winpw = data.azurerm_key_vault.keyvault.id[count.index]
}
}

resource "local_file" "wininv" {
count = ${var.cnt} 
content = data.template_files.wininv[count.index]
filename = "ansible/inventory.cfg"

}
```

Here, I want fetch azure secret, if available on keyvault and generate template.

Without "count" code, its working well, but when secret is not available on azure that time getting error in Terraform. *That stuff i have to control.*

But with this code, getting below error:

```
Error: incorrect attributes value type
On test.tf in data template_files" "wininv":

66    var ={ 

inappropriate value for attribute string required vars: elements example : String required
```

Can you please suggest possible Syntex or any alternative solution for same.

Thanks

Comment: What is `keyvault`? Its definition is not shown.

Comment: Also where is `Var ={ ` in your code? The error does not match your code in the question.

Comment: @Marcin Var = {  is on template section. Without count, terraform script working well. I updated my question for more clarity.

Answer (score 1):

[template_file](https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/template/latest/docs/data-sources/file) requires **string only** attributes. It should be:

```
winpw = data.azurerm_key_vault.keyvault[count.index].id
```

Also these days its recommended to use [templatefile](https://www.terraform.io/language/functions/templatefile) over `template_file`.

Answer (score 1):

[Conditional Expressions](https://www.terraform.io/language/expressions/conditionals) may solve your problem.

```
data "template_files" "wininv"{
  count = ${var.cnt} # either 0 and 1
  template = file(ansible/inventory.tpl)
  var = {
    winpw = ${var.cnt} == 0 ? "" : data.azurerm_key_vault.keyvault[count.index].id
  }
}
```

You need to use `rendered` attritube to get the rendered template. ([doc](https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/template/latest/docs/data-sources/file#attributes-reference))

```
resource "local_file" "wininv" {
  count = ${var.cnt} 
  content = data.template_files.wininv[count.index].rendered  # NOTICE rendered
  filename = "ansible/inventory.cfg"
}
```

Comment: Oh, Marcin is right. No need to use conditional expression.

Comment: Here we have to use .value, not a .Id
Thanks it's helpful